# Reading to newline from serial port returning first value

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port

I'm trying to read data from a serial port that I have an Arduino and joystick connected to.

When trying to print out the received data to check if I'm getting it, it continues to print out the same value it was at when it connected.

I am sending data from my serial port in this format: Xaxis:yAxis:switchBool

Heres my C# code in a WPF application

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window {

  public Timer loopTimer;
  string comport = "COM7";
  SerialPort sp;

  public MainWindow() {
    InitializeComponent();
    SetTimer();
    OpenPort();
  }

  private void SetTimer() {
    //Setup the timer
    loopTimer = new Timer(500);
    // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
    loopTimer.Elapsed += TryRead;
    loopTimer.AutoReset = true;
    loopTimer.Enabled = false;
  }

  public void OpenPort() {
    sp = new SerialPort();
    try {
      string portName = comport;
      sp.PortName = portName;
      sp.BaudRate = 9600;
      sp.Open();
      Debug.WriteLine("Connected");
      loopTimer.Enabled = true;
    }
    catch (Exception) {
      MessageBox.Show("Please give a valid port number or check your connection");
      loopTimer.Enabled = false;
    }
  }

  public void TryRead(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string s = sp.ReadLine();
    Debug.WriteLine(s);
    Debug.WriteLine("-");
  }
}
```

Here's my arduino code:

```
int xPin = A1;
int yPin = A0;
int swPin = A2;
float deadzone = .05;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(swPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  float xVal =  (((analogRead(xPin) + 1) / 1023.) * 2) -1;
  if (xVal < deadzone && xVal > -deadzone ) {
    xVal = 0; 
  }

  float yVal =  (((analogRead(yPin) + 1) / 1023.) * 2) -1;
  if (yVal < deadzone && yVal > -deadzone ) {
    yVal = 0; 
  }

  int swVal = analogRead(swPin);
  bool switchDown;

  if (swVal == 0) {
    switchDown = true;
  } else {
    switchDown = false;
  }
   
  Serial.println( String(xVal) + ":" + String(yVal) + ":" + switchDown);
}
```

Here's an example of what the data should and does look like in the Arduino's serial monitor when moving the thumbstick around:

> -1.00:0.70:0
> -0.80:0.50:0
> -0.70:0.60:0

Running my C# code above and not moving the thumbstick I only get `0.00:0.00:0.00` every time I read, and if I move it before starting I will only receive whatever value that was.

Comment: The timer must be starting because its printing out the value at the given interval. I am using ```loopTimer.enabled = true;```  after opening the port to set it off, but adding ```loopTimer.Start();``` alongside it makes no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of reading on an interval I would just read whenever new data arrives on the bus. below is an example of how to do that.

```
SerialPort Port= new SerialPort("Com7");
Port.DataReceived+=OnSerialRecieve;
```

```
private void OnSerialRecieve(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((sender as SerialPort).IsOpen)
    {
        string DataRecieved=(sender as SerialPort).ReadExisting();
    }
}
```

from there you can split it up as you need to. otherwise if you know the exact amount of data your expecting you can sue SerialPort.ReadByte to read exactly the number of bytes you need.

Comment: After implementing that the data is reading new values correctly, but it appears that it is reading the data before its all there. Ive added ```Debug.WriteLine(DataReceived);``` and taken out the timer and [heres](https://gyazo.com/72074775ef4a26b473fd9ca0ae2b5ac0) the result

Comment: @loganm That is correct! it will read the data anytime it arrives ( when you call serial.println on your arduino it doesnt all send at once it sends each character one at a time). Next you can put a delimiter character (like a semicolon) and split the data up. or you can set it up to read into a buffer and from there split it up into x byte chunks ( where x is however many characters your packets are)